# How to user custom Drag Appearance in smart gwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am trying to user Custom Drag appearance in smart gwt. how can i implement it.
Current when using DragAppearance.TRACKER its show on 10px square i want a lable with caption Drag to Lineup.

```
vLayout1.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.TRACKER);
vLayout1.setCanHover(true);
vLayout1.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, the following links will help you

https://github.com/moravianlibrary/MEditor/blob/master/editor-editation/src/main/java/cz/mzk/editor/client/view/ModifyView.java#L1100:L1104

https://github.com/moravianlibrary/MEditor/blob/master/editor-common/editor-common-client/src/main/java/cz/mzk/editor/client/view/other/EditorDragMoveHandler.java

Answer (score 0):

Override [BaseWidget.setDragTracker](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/BaseWidget.html#setDragTracker%28%29) and provide required content using [EventHandler.setDragTracker](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/util/EventHandler.html#setDragTracker%28java.lang.String%29).

```
VLayout vLayout1 = new VLayout() {
    @Override
    protected boolean setDragTracker() {
        EventHandler.setDragTracker("<pre>Drag to Lineup</pre>");
        return false;
    }
};
vLayout1.setCanDrop(true);
vLayout1.setCanDrag(true);
vLayout1.setDragAppearance(DragAppearance.TRACKER);
```

EventHandler.setDragTracker accepts any valid html code and `<pre/>` tags were used above to avoid word wrap.

Check following sample in SmartGWT showcase:
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_dd_tracker